# Dynamically Create dropdownlist in a formview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am quite new in `ASP NET` and `C#` programming. I facing some problem when i want to create a dropdownlist in a formview.

```
private void CreateDropDownList(string ID)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = ID;
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));

    //ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
    //ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnSelectedIndexChanged);

    pnlDropDownList.Controls.Add(ddl);

    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Text = "<br />";
    pnlDropDownList.Controls.Add(lt);
}
```

The code above are okay to create a button outside the formview, but when i put my button ***inside*** the formview, it does not work.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to populate `CreateDropDownList` in `FormView1_DataBound`

Comment: Sorry that i am quite new to it... Is that any example or sample code for me to refer? Thanks...

Comment: sure .. give me a min

Comment: protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = null;
            if(FormView1.Row != null)
                ddl = (DropDownList) FormView1.Row.FindControl("drodownlistid");
     ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));

        }

Comment: The solution you give can generate the dropdownlist, but the problem i face is: i call the function using "Add Person" button in formview, but cannot generate the dropdownlist. I need a button to generate the dropdownlist one by one, and need to be after the button "Add Person" which is in the formview.

Comment: oh you didnt mentioned this in your question ..

Comment: only thing you asked is creating dropdownlist in formview

Comment: Sorry about that... is that possible to generate dropdownlist one by one using button?

Comment: Yes, i think for the question you asked matched my solution rite ??  can you accept it and ask another question fully

Answer (score 0):

For the question you asked this is my solution. if you have another question please start it as a new question

```
 protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 

{ 
      DropDownList ddl = null;
     if(FormView1.Row != null) 
     ddl = (DropDownList)FormView1.Row.FindControl("drodownlistid");  
     ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
 }
```